# how to set Outlook rule to check if you are the only one on the TO: line

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

How to set an Outlook rule to find emails where you are the ONLY one on the TO: line.  There are rule options for determining if email was sent ONLY to you, but I need to identify where my email address is the ONLY one on the "TO:" line but there may be others who where copied on the "CC:" line.  There is a way to HIGHLIGHT these, but I need to be able to identify and MOVE them to another folder for quick access.

Comment: Is this something you're just going to do periodically, or something you want to apply to each email as it comes in?  You could create a new view with a filter on "Where I am: the only person on the To line" and periodically go to that view, select all, and drag to the folder.

Comment: I asked the same question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1684195/outlook-rule-for-messages-for-while-i-am-the-only-name-in-the-to-box/1684214#1684214) without realizing this one was already out there. There's currently one answer involving the use of search folders.

Comment: I tried this today with Outlook 2019 and it doesn't seem possible with the provided conditions. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is super old, but I just got here with the same question, so I'm going to answer in case someone else does, too.

There are now (in 2022) some options in the Rules Wizard (i.e., the pop-up that walks you through setting-up the rules) to help you with this. If you have trouble reaching it, type "rules" into the search bar in Outlook.

On the "which condition(s) do you want to check?" page of the wizard, check the box next to "sent only to me."

And/Or, on the "Are there any exceptions?" page of the Rules Wizard (i.e., the pop-up that walks you through setting-up the rules), check the box for "except if sent only to me."

[Screenshot: the Outlook Rules wizard exceptions page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrAJ.png)

Comment: This is not the rule OP asked for. If an email is sent **TO** *User A* and **CC** *User B* the rule with the "sent only to me" will not be triggered for *User A* since the mail was also "sent to" *User B* (through **CC**). The condition "Only sent to me" literally means: "No one else received this email". Op wants a filter where he is addressed as the sole **TO** recipient.

Answer (score -1):

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
where my name is in the To box
move it to the [whatever] folder
```

Comment: This would trigger also if his address is among several recipients in the To-field.