# Outlook rule for messages for while I am the only name in the "To:" box

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules, email-filter

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1243834/is-it-possible-to-divide-my-outlook-inbox-to-me-and-cc-to-me/1244033) I'd like to filter my messages based on how prominently they feature me in the address list. I often get important messages that look like this:

```
To: <me>
Cc: <one or more people>
```

The fact that I'm the only person on the "To" line signals that these are important messages for me, but Outlook's built-in "Sent only to me filter" won't pick them up for me because there are other people CC-ed. Is there some way I can move messages where I'm the only To address, regardless of who's CC-ed?

FWIW I'm running Office Pro 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a test in my lab, I cannot create a rule to filter the messages that the To filed is only you. But I have found that I can Color-code email messages sent only to you, follow these steps to do these:
[image]
For more details: [Color-code email messages sent only to you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/color-code-email-messages-sent-only-to-you-83c150ab-2c69-43c3-ae4f-73912f594f9e)

Comment: It's funny that "Where I am the only person on the To line" is one of the options presented most prominently by the UI in your method yet isn't available at all with rules.

Comment: I'm not clear what you said that it isn't available at all with rules? could you clarify it clearly? Or the method was provided by Allen J work for you?

Comment: Hi @Joy Zhang. Allen J's solution works except it creates a search folder (a sort of virtual folder that shows links to existing messages) rather than letting me actually move the message in question to the folder of my choice.

Comment: At present, I have done some research and testing in my lab, but I haven't found a way to configure rules to meet your request, I believe these 2 methods are good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure OP is the only recipient in the To: line by using a "Search Folder" with Advanced criteria.

1. Right-click on "Search Folders" and choose "New Search Folder...".
2. Scroll to the bottom and select "Create a custom Search Folder".
3. Click "Choose..." and name the Search something like "Only Person in To:"
4. Click "Criteria..." then the "Advanced" tab.
5. Add To: field and your email address with condition "is (exactly)".
6. Add Cc: field with the condition "is not empty".

[image: Outlook Advanced Search Criteria]

This should work on Outlook 2013-2021 and 365.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options in the Rules Wizard (i.e., the pop-up that walks you through setting-up the rules) to help you with this. If you have trouble reaching it, type "rules" into the search bar in Outlook.

On the "which condition(s) do you want to check?" page of the wizard, check the box next to "sent only to me."

And/Or, on the "Are there any exceptions?" page of the Rules Wizard (i.e., the pop-up that walks you through setting-up the rules), check the box for "except if sent only to me."

[Screenshot: the Outlook Rules wizard exceptions page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrAJ.png)